# Problem with how to set many rasters at the same projection and crs

Tags: r, raster, coordinate-systems

Good morning to you all. I am sorry if this section is missing some information, but this is the first time I am using it.
I have a problem with several raster layers in R. The problem is that when I load them, they do not have the same projections, or so I thought, because when I represent them the localities are spatially deformed. They are New Zealand layers.
I need to put them in the same geographical position because I have collection points and these do not coincide with the geographical localities because they are displaced.
I have tried to do the following function and the data I think that if I know the raster I think it is fixed, but in the representation of the raster it is blank.

Function :

```
Humedad (Humidity) <- projectRaster(Humedad (Humidity), NewZealand)
```

When I write crs(Humedad):

```
crs(Humedad)
Coordinate Reference System:
Deprecated Proj.4 representation:
 +proj=nzmg +lat_0=-41 +lon_0=173 +x_0=2510000 +y_0=6023150 +ellps=intl
+units=m +no_defs 
WKT2 2019 representation:
PROJCRS["NZGD49 / New Zealand Map Grid",
    BASEGEOGCRS["NZGD49",
        DATUM["New Zealand Geodetic Datum 1949",
            ELLIPSOID["International 1924",6378388,297,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        ID["EPSG",4272]],
    CONVERSION["New Zealand Map Grid",
        METHOD["New Zealand Map Grid",
            ID["EPSG",9811]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",-41,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",173,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",2510000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",6023150,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["(E)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        AXIS["(N)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["Engineering survey, topographic mapping."],
        AREA["New Zealand - North Island, South Island, Stewart Island - onshore."],
        BBOX[-47.33,166.37,-34.1,178.63]],
    ID["EPSG",27200]]
```

with crs(NewZealand):

```
Coordinate Reference System:
Deprecated Proj.4 representation:
 +proj=nzmg +lat_0=-41 +lon_0=173 +x_0=2510000 +y_0=6023150 +ellps=intl
+units=m +no_defs 
WKT2 2019 representation:
PROJCRS["NZGD49 / New Zealand Map Grid",
    BASEGEOGCRS["NZGD49",
        DATUM["New Zealand Geodetic Datum 1949",
            ELLIPSOID["International 1924",6378388,297,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        ID["EPSG",4272]],
    CONVERSION["New Zealand Map Grid",
        METHOD["New Zealand Map Grid",
            ID["EPSG",9811]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",-41,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",173,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",2510000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",6023150,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["(E)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        AXIS["(N)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["Engineering survey, topographic mapping."],
        AREA["New Zealand - North Island, South Island, Stewart Island - onshore."],
        BBOX[-47.33,166.37,-34.1,178.63]],
    ID["EPSG",27200]]
```

I hope someone can help me, as I need to make special models and I can't figure this out.
Tnaks for everything.

I have tried to configure several raster maps to the same extent or crs as they differ in their geographical representation.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your raster data so that your issue can be reproduced?

Comment: Sorry, but being new I don't know how to share raster files on the forum. I tried to do it as an image but it didn't work because of its size. I also tried the system.file("file path", package="raster") function, but it comes out as text, not as a downloadable file. If you can help me to do it I would be very grateful.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15821/stack-overflow-etiquette-for-sharing-files-and-resources) ressource might be handy.